# How can I use polygon grid to export raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, export, fme-form, saga

I have a polygon grid which consists of 100 square polygons. For each square I need to export the raster overlay. I have ArcGIS 10.0, FME 2014, Saga-GIS. Is there a suitable tool for this or do I need to script something with Python or Model builder?

Answer (score 2):

I am not really sure about what exactly you need to do.
Do yours 100 grid polygons snap to pixels of raster? (1 polygon = 1 pixel)
And do you need to extract raster values into polygon grid?
If it is sufficient for you only to **extract raster pixel data** **and do have it in** **one table**, you can firstly (in ArcGIS):

1. convert raster to points (`conversion->From Raster->Raster to Point`)
   and than
2. extract raster pixel values into this new points.shp
   (`Spatial analysis->Extraction->Extract Values to Points`) or if you have multiple rasters use `Extract Multi Values to Points` (Warning! with zero value it doesnt work very well!)
3. export attribute table with values for each pixel (look maybe here: http://www.geoplanit.co.uk/?p=21)

If you would like to use polygons, dont you want to try **convert Raster to Polygon**? (`conversion->From Raster->Raster to Polygon`) and overlay it than with your 100 polygons grid?

Hope it helps, or thy to specify your question

Comment: Nein. I have a project area of around 500km². I have a single raster image covering the whole area. I have created a 2km²x2km² grid covering the project area, and now need to extract the underlying raster image for each cell of the grid.